# How can we show helptext of a field in VF page

Tags: visualforce, jquery, slds

I am using fieldsets to display fields in a VF page. Is there a way to display the help text icon  next to the label if there is a help text associated with the field and display the text on hover?

**Update**
I am not using pageblocks as we are using slds. Though the code below doesnt exactly use slds but the logic would be similar except for html and classes different.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!AppFields}" var="f"> 

               <div class="form-group">

                     <!--  <td class="tdStyleFirst">  -->
                      <div class="control-label col-xs-3">
                         <apex:outputlabel styleclass="control-label " value="{!f.Label}"  /><apex:outputLabel value="*" style="color:red;font-weight:bold" rendered="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}" />
                     </div>                
                     <div class="control-label col-xs-9">

                          <apex:inputField value="{!apps[f.fieldPath]}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbrequired)}"  styleClass="form-control" />
                      </div>                         
                </div>        

          </apex:repeat>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Html  css to achieve this

here is our css

```
div.tooltip {
     width: 20px;
     float: right;
     display:inline;
}

div.tooltip span {
     display: none;
     font-weight:normal;
     text-align:left;
     padding: 3px 5px;
     margin-left: 8px;
    width: 250px;
}

div.tooltip:hover span {
display: inline;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
background: #FFC;
color: #000000;
z-index:10000;
}
```

now use your css in html code

```
<div class="helpOrb tooltip" style="position:relative;left:10px">
   <span>
       help text
   </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, this seems a duplicate of [How to add field help text in visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65683/how-to-add-field-help-text-in-visualforce-page)

But, as you are using fieldsets. Let me add on how to achieve this using fieldsets.

You can do dynamic binding to show helptext and it's icon. See below example.

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Automatic">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSet}" var="member">
                <apex:outputField value="{!MyObject__c[member]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Dynamic Binding">
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.FieldSets.MyFieldSet}" var="member">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Object__c.fields[member].inlineHelpText}">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!member.label}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!MyObject__c[member]}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Here in the `pageblocksection` **Automatic**, you will get the helptext automatically as we are using `outputField`, same is applicable for `inputField`

In in the `pageblocksection` **Dynamic Binding**, you will see the helptext is set by us in `pageBlockSectionItem` as we are using `outputText`, same is applicable for `inputText`. Here the helptext from the object is fetched and displayed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry. I should have been little more clear on my question. I am not using pageblocks as it's using slds.

Comment: Can you paste your code in the question?

Comment: Updated the question with code